# Very low current (<10 microamps) darkness detector circuit that turns off in light

Tags: led, low-power, photodiode, phototransistor, light-sensor

I've made a device that lights an LED at a very low current (<10 microamps) as a very dim indicator for use in the dark.

At its simplest, the circuit is a 3V coin battery + resistor (300K-1M ohms) + LED.

I'd like it to turn off when there's ambient light in the room and, ideally, draw no power whatsoever to save the small battery it runs on.

The darkness detectors I'm aware of, however, use a transistor and photo detector to accomplish this (see https://www.buildcircuit.com/darklight-sensor-using-transistor/), and typically draw power in ambient light when the LED is turned off.  These work at when running the LED at ~10-20mA, but just tinkering, I haven't been able to make these function at the low <10uA currents I'm trying to work with.

Any ideas on a better way to switch off a low current LED circuit entirely when light is detected?

Thanks --

Comment: One possible approach would be to only turn the photo detector on for a few microseconds every few seconds.

Comment: @NateStrickland But then you have to worry about the power consumed by the device that does the timing and controls the photo detector...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, that's absolutely true, but there are very low power devices available for this purpose, since periodically waking up to check some sensor is a common requirement.  Granted, they're mostly MCUs that will require some programming.

Comment: Add a 10uA capable solar panel and let the LED run all day

Comment: You might want to compare the work of https://hackaday.io/project/11864-tritiled , which achieves multi year battery life with a small microcontroller powering a boost controller.

Comment: @sstobbe Why solar?  Just use a rechargeable battery or a larger 3V lithium battery.  A CR2032 will last about 100 days if left on 24 hrs a day @ 10µA. Adding a photo detector will add years to your ROI.   A solar panel is never a good idea when utility electric is available. Solar also needs a rechargeable battery and MPPT charger.  Not likely there would ever be an ROI with a solar panel.  1 kW (10¢) will run this circuit over 30 million hours.  Should only be battery powered if utility electric is not possible.

Comment: @Misunderstood The OPs question was for a photo detector that consumes little power. A solar panel is exactly that during the day it consumes no power, in fact it provides power. I don't know what the OPs widget is, so I can't speak to its utility or use case.

Comment: @sstobbe What I am saying is the ROI on adding just the photo detector (parts and labor) would be years.  Adding a solar panel would likely never pay off.  One could buy a lifetime of batteries for this circuit getting paid for working 1 hour.  The easiest way to improve the circuit is to use a higher efficacy LED like a Cree XP-G3 or Luxeon C Line.   You should be able to run either of these LEDs 5 years on a CR2032.  If you add a spot lens you can greatly increase the intensity with a collimated  beam and reduce the current even more.

Comment: @Misunderstood By solar panel, I mean a series string of solar cells arranged into panel like found in a dollar store solar calculator or garden light, the panel is pennies. However I completely agree that strictly for ROI, buying a few extra batteries is cheaper (not the OPs question though).

Answer (score 1):

At 10 microamps, you could just add a solar cell and a (very) low leakage diode. Any reasonable amount of light would then power your circuit instead of the battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv6CQF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The very small current back into the battery can safely be ignored, and the bas116 has nA range leakage current.

Answer (score 0):

Why is this battery powered?  If battery is not required then a linear 3V supply would do well.

10 µA is a bit on the high side. You should be able to get down in the sub 1 µA realm.
Depends upon whether you want to illuminate the room or the LED just be visible across the room.

There is no ROI in turning off the LED when the room is not dark. You should be able to get the LED to last years on a single CR2032. A single CR2032 should last 3 years @ 10 µA.

[This project](https://hackaday.io/project/11864-tritiled/log/48402-version-21-5-years-on-a-cr2032-in-19-different-colors#j-discussions-title) claims 5 years with a single CR2032. And it uses a cheap low efficacy LEDs.
The highest efficacy LED today (Feb 2019) is a [Samsung LM301B](https://cdn.samsung.com/led/file/resource/2018/09/Data_Sheet_LM301B_CRI70_Rev.4.1.pdf). This LED has an efficacy of more than 150% that of the LED used in this project.  The LM301B is the LED you want to use. That should extend the 5 years to more than 7.5 years.

Using a flashing LED will extend the life span.  A 200 mS pulse every second will increase battery life 5X or 37.5 years when combined with the LM301B.  The afore mentioned project uses a PIC µController. Is the cost and amount of work to add a µController worth 5 batteries?  Don't think so.  And a boost converter is not needed because a lithium battery has a very flat discharge curve. Boost comes at a cost of reduced efficiency.

A 3V lithium battery and a resistor is all you need.  Let it run 24/7.

To possibly make it more efficient use a step down voltage regulator and no resistor.
For an LM301B you would need a voltage of about 2.2V